# Hangman JUnit testing

Tags: java, junit

I have a project for Hangman game application that reads guesses from the console input and to make unit testing for it, but i don't know how to test it. They told me to make it return true or false on the last method, because my code is untestable and that will help me to test it like i play the game /to win and to lose/. But i don't know how to do it. Can someone help me to test it?

here is my code:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private String secredWord;
private StringBuilder dashes;
private int lives;
private int guesses;
private char[] wrongGuess;

/**
 * Generates a string with all letters in the searched word replaced with an
 * underline and a space.
 * 
 * @return return the secred word hidden.
 */
public StringBuilder makeDashes() {
    dashes = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < secredWord.length(); i++) {
        dashes.append("_ ");

    }
    return dashes;
}

/**
 * Takes a string as a parameter and set the sacred word to be guessed, and
 * reset the lives & guesses that are made.
 * 
 * @param secredWord
 *            the word that has to be guessed.
 * 
 * @return - returns the method that make the word hidde.
 */
public StringBuilder setGame(String secredWord) {
    this.secredWord = secredWord;
    lives = 0;
    guesses = 0;
    wrongGuess = new char[6];

    return makeDashes();
}

/**
 * Make a check for a repeatable guesses.
 * 
 * @param guess
 *            Characters to check
 * @return - returns true or false. If true it make you guess another
 *         character.
 */
private boolean repeatGuesses(char guess) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dashes.length(); i = i + 2) {
        if (dashes.charAt(i) == guess) {
            return true;

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wrongGuess.length; i++) {
        if (wrongGuess[i] == guess) {
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;

}

/**
 * Reads a letter and check if its been guessed before.
 */
private void guessLetter() {
    char guess;
    boolean present = false;

    LOGGER.info("Make a guess: ");
    guess = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    while (repeatGuesses(guess)) {
        LOGGER.info("The letter has been guessed already!");
        LOGGER.info("Make another guess: ");
        guess = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < secredWord.length(); i++) {
        if (secredWord.charAt(i) == guess) {
            dashes.setCharAt(i * 2, guess);
            present = true;
            guesses++;

        }

    }
    if (!present) {
        LOGGER.info("Wrong guess");
        wrongGuess[lives++] = guess;

    }
}

/**
 * While you didnt guess the word or you have more lifes left calls the
 * motod guessLetter() and you have to make a guess untill you lost your
 * lifes or guess the word.
 */
public void playTheGame() {
    while (lives < 6 && guesses < secredWord.length()) {
        LOGGER.info("Hidden word --> {}", dashes);
        LOGGER.info("Lives: ({}/6 wrong letters)", lives);
        guessLetter();

    }
    if (lives == 6) {
        LOGGER.info("You lost!The word was --> {}", secredWord);
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Congratulations YOU WON!!! The word was --> {}.", secredWord);

    }
}
```

And make one test to see is the word hidden `

```
public void hiddenWordTest() {
    HangmanGame item = new HangmanGame();

    String secredWord = "hangman";

    String correctHidden = "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ ";
    StringBuilder resultHidden = item.setGame(secredWord);
    assertEquals(correctHidden, resultHidden.toString());

}`
```

Comment: You should extract core methods related to the game logic and then test only those if they return correct values for a given input.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1. You can pass in LOGGER via contructor and fake it during a test
2. Extract computation logic into separate class and test that in isolation without any fakes.